# Disable MDI child Form buttons

Tags: vb6

Is there possible to disable child's form buttons from parent form?
For example, I have 2 radio-buttons in parent form, one is True second False, when I choose one of them fires radiobutton.CheckedChanged event and there I have code what goes like this, but it's not working:

```
ChildForm.Button1.Enabled = False
```

where seems to be the problem? Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you sure this is VB6 ? isn't it VB.Net ?

Comment: You can also make a public funtion on the child form which can enable/disable the radiobutton. Then call this public function from your parent form.

Comment: I don't really know because it is in Application not web

Comment: why don't you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Hrqls Already tried... nothing... :(

Comment: have you tried plain `Button1.Enabled = false;`? also, check to make sure the name and case are done correctly. These are case sensitive. It is really hard to say unless you provide us with the code you already have

Comment: please post the code where you load and show the child form, and post the whole function/sub where you disable the radio buttons .. please edit your post with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create an instance of the childform.

So...

```
ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
cf.Button1.Enabled = false;
```

You have to keep in mind though, it could be a different instance than the child form that is currently being shown.

To be sure, depending on your code (which I can't see) and how your program is laid out I would probably do something like this...

```
ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
cf.show();
cf.Button1.Enabled = false;
```

so here I know that the ChildForm that is showing is the one that has the button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 the following project works:

1 MDI form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MDIForm_Click()
  Form1.Option1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub MDIForm_Load()
  Form1.Show
End Sub
```

Form1 is a MDI child form with 2 radio buttons on it